# Why is file upload button not finding its CSS styles

Tags: css, angularjs

Here is a [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLnnbLwc/3/) illustrating the problem. In this example some of the Angular code is also broken, but that's just a result of it being pasted to jFiddle; it's not really a problem I'm experience.

However I can't seem to apply the CSS stles to the "Select File" button.

```
  <button type="menu-open-button" name="menu-open-button" ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)"
            accept="image/*">
        Select File</button>
```

In real life I've included a `<link>` to the corresponding style sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `type` to `class`,

```
<button class="menu-open-button"  ngf-select="uploadFiles($file, $invalidFiles)" accept="image/*">
 Select File
</button>
```

[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7tr0dzd7/1/)

Comment: When I copy the CSS for `menu-open-button` and rename it to `file-upload-button` and update the class accordingly, the CSS style is no longer applied. You don't happen to know why that is, do you?

Comment: it should work! check here https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7tr0dzd7/1/